# i have a problem with strings and for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string and I saved it inside a variable.
I want to change even characters to capitalize with for loop.
so i  give my even characters and capitalized it. But
i cant bring them with odd characters .
can someone help me?

here is my code:

````
name = "mohammadhosein"
>>> for even in range(0, len(name), 2):
...     if(even % 2 == 0):
...        print(name[even].title(), end=' ')
...
M H M A H S I >>>
>>> ###### I want print it like this:MoHaMmAdHoSeIn```
````

Comment: @mohammadhosein, can you provide an example of what you want to achieve? I would be useful if you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: All you need to do is remove the 2 in your loop. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are quite new to programing, so use a the following for loop:

```
name = "mohammadhosein"
output = ''
for i, c in enumerate(name):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        output += c.upper()
    else:
        output += c

# output will be 'MoHaMmAdHoSeIn'
```

`enumerate` will give you a pair of `(i, c)` where `i` is an index, starting at 0, and `c` is a character of `name`.

If you feel more comfortable with code you can use a list comprehension and join the results as follows:

```py
>>> ''.join([c.upper() if i % 2 == 0 else c for i, c in enumerate(name)])
'MoHaMmAdHoSeIn'
```

As @SimonN has suggested, you just needed to make some small changes to your code:

```py
for index in range(0, len(name)):
    if(index % 2 == 0):
        print(name[index].upper(), end='') # use upper instead of title it is more readable
    else:
        print(name[index], end='')
print()
```

Comment: Yes i am new i have  started to learn python for3 hours.and im 12 yrs old.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: By the way, the reason your original code didn't work was just because you specified a step size of 2 in 'range'. That means your 'if' is completely pointless as you're only looking at the even numbers, and only printing the even numbers. If you just got rid of the 2 from range your original code would pretty much work.

Comment: @SimonN, thanks for your comment. I updated the answer. You are right, and your comment is useful considering somebody is new to code. You usually want to understand why your code is not working.